# Got Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

Tags: android, eclipse, android-tablayout, android-support-design

I'm trying to create a menu tab based on Google's "material design" using Eclipse, but I got an error:

```
    01-07 01:02:10.238: E/tag(6696): contact on create called
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rvappsstudios.designflashalerts/com.rvappsstudios.designflashalerts.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rvappsstudios.designflashalerts/com.rvappsstudios.designflashalerts.Contact_mainfragment}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rvappsstudios.designflashalerts/com.rvappsstudios.designflashalerts.Contact_mainfragment}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2186)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at com.rvappsstudios.designflashalerts.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     ... 11 more
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at com.rvappsstudios.designflashalerts.Contact_mainfragment.onCreate(Contact_mainfragment.java:25)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     ... 21 more
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     ... 32 more
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.design.R$styleable
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.<init>(TabLayout.java:234)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.<init>(TabLayout.java:219)
    01-07 01:02:10.301: E/AndroidRuntime(6696):     ... 35 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have described it on my blog.

http://www.geeksmember.blogspot.in/2015/10/errorerror-inflating-class.html

I also answered the similar question on stackoverflow as well. See this question's answer.

[Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TabLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712563/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-tablayout/32895215#32895215)

Comment: it hasn't solved it in my case.. any help as to why?
Thanks!