# Application works on emulator but doesn't work on mobile device

Tags: android, android-studio

I Created a Tic tac toe game on android studio. I ran fine on the emulator. but didn't run on the mobile device. I tried every possible solution but can't find one. Please help me with this.

This is the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.nigam.tictactoe2, PID: 8035
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nigam.tictactoe2/com.nigam.tictactoe2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.widget.GridLayout
```

activity_main.xml: Everything on activity_main.xml seems fine too.This is the activity_main.xml file:

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="365dp"
    android:layout_height="407dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gridboard"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.666"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="121dp"
        android:layout_height="139dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:tag="0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView18"
        android:layout_width="121dp"
        android:layout_height="139dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:tag="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView25"
        android:layout_width="121dp"
        android:layout_height="139dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:tag="2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView24"
        android:layout_width="121dp"
        android:layout_height="139dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:tag="3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView23"
        android:layout_width="121dp"
        android:layout_height="139dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:tag="4" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView22"
        android:layout_width="121dp"
        android:layout_height="139dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:tag="5" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView21"
        android:layout_width="121dp"
        android:layout_height="139dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:tag="6" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView20"
        android:layout_width="121dp"
        android:layout_height="139dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:tag="7" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView19"
        android:layout_width="121dp"
        android:layout_height="139dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:tag="8" />
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Firstly share your main activity XML file.

Comment: What version of Android is your physical device running?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TabLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712563/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-tablayout)

Comment: @Jahnold It doesn't run on any of the devices.