# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am trying to implement Tab Layout but unfortunately getting this error ,

i have added my xml code ,can anyone help figuring out what i am doing incorrectly.

the following is the error log i get

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vvdntech.design_material/com.example.vvdntech.design_material.LoggedIn}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2667)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1494)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:467)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.example.vvdntech.design_material.LoggedIn.onCreate(LoggedIn.java:17)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6582)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2532)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2667) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1494) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:467) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.example.vvdntech.design_material.LoggedIn.onCreate(LoggedIn.java:17) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6582) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.vvdntech.design_material-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.vvdntech.design_material-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
```

This is the xml file i have

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoggedIn">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pager">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:icon="@drawable/b"
                android:text="tab1" />
            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:icon="@drawable/b"
                android:text="tab2"/>
            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:icon="@drawable/b"
                android:text="tab3"/>

        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main Activity i haven't added anything yet. this is totally practice , so if any small mistakes in code , do tell.

EDIT :  i am also attaching my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.vvdntech.design_material"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
}
```

& https://material.io/develop/android/components/tab-layout/ i am using this link where the tab is inside view pager.

thnx in advance

Comment: TabLayout should be outside the viewpager and you need to connect them in java file using setupViewPager(); method

Comment: Post your java class.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712563/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-tablayout

Comment: Make sure you have Design Support Library

Comment: @Ankita java class i havent added anything

Comment: @KushaalSingla i have the support library & according to new way it can be inside the view pager too

Comment: @AnkitDubey i already checked the link , nothing works

Comment: @AnjaniMittal Did you found the solution , i am facing the same issue .

Answer (score 8):

The source of the error is that `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout` does not come from the support libraries but rather from the material design library as @Doflaminhgo pointed out.

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    // ...
}
```

Reference https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

I am not sure why the Android [reference documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout) describes use of Material Components without apparently mentioning where to find it anywhere in the section.

Comment: this is only incase u r using androidx artifacts, actually in case of the question asker, this will result in compile error because of mixing androidx and support dependencies

Answer (score 5):

this is a bit late, but for anyone who might be looking into this for the future:

the package you need to use is **not com.google.android.material.tabs** (although it is the one used in the material design website), but it is **android.support.design.widget** instead (both for TabLayout and TabItem). here is an example usage:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
            android:text="Active"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
            android:text="History"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
            android:text="Ignored"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Comment: If anyone is looking at this answer now, please note that if you are using Android then you actually need the material dependency and not the support one.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed [here](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/) and [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/298#issuecomment-471420831), your app should use a theme that inherits `Theme.MaterialComponents` themes or should have desired attributes.

Comment: This is kinda my issue. In my case, the other device that I was used is on dark mode, and I haven't setup the dark mode theme as my previous device isn't using that. I just copied the content of the original theme to the dark mode theme, and the error just fixed

Answer (score 4):

It could be that it's looking for values which don't exist in your current app theme. Therefore, make sure your app theme starts with `Theme.MaterialComponents` instead of `Theme.AppCompat`.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with Tablayout(lib Masterial), and solved it as follows

Add style.xml

```
<style name="ThemeCustom.TabLayout" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"/>
```

layout.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeCustom.TabLayout">

</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

It solved my problem. Hope it helps others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

May your xml file version is limited...

[image]

also see this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32895215/9868485)

Answer (score 0):

Go through your support libraries in gradle file, all support libs must have the same version, probably issue of mixed versions.

Comment: added the gradle , no mismatch in version

Answer (score 0):

On my activity_main it was saying only tablayout but I have changed to the com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout and the problem got fixed

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer [from the maintainer](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/340#issuecomment-551584072).

> theme must be `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"` or its inherit

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)