# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout and ClassNotFoundException: android.support.design.R$styleable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am developing an app which have Tab with swipe functionality. I am using Eclipse to develop. I have imported the `support design library` as Library through Property. During run, i am keep getting this error "`Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`".

1. First i added `android support design.jar` and tried, which is not working
2. I added the `class.jar` file of `support design library` through J`ava build path` which is not worked
3. Finally i imported the `support design library` as Library using `Properties->Android->Add Library` this also not working
4. I am using the Parent theme as "`Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`"

"`<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`"

5. I am extending the `AppCompatActivity`, see my MainActivity.Java

   package com.example.scrollingtab.activity;

   ```
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import com.example.scrollingtab.R;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

       private Toolbar toolbar;
       private Button btnSimpleTabs, btnScrollableTabs, btnIconTextTabs, btnIconTabs, btnCustomIconTextTabs;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
           setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

           btnSimpleTabs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSimpleTabs);

           btnSimpleTabs.setOnClickListener(this);

       }
   ```

Below is the full stack trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.scrollingtab, PID: 1348
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.scrollingtab/com.example.scrollingtab.activity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
at com.example.scrollingtab.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/design/R$styleable;
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:171)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:165)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.R$styleable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.scrollingtab-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.design.R$styleable
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

I have tried most of the things talked and provided by SO. Still i am not able to trace what is wrong in my program.

Need help to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to add NavigationView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964009/unable-to-add-navigationview)

Answer (score 51):

I got this error while Migrating to AndroidX

To resolve I did:

1. as suggested by @Mikeumus -  and added this to the module's build.gradle dependencies:

   **implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:latest.version.here'**
2. check in the Layout XML file (the layout that you're trying to launch with ***setContentView***

if the Layout contains:
<**`android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`** ...

replace that with : **`<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout`**

3. in the same layout file - replace the closing tag

`</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`

with

`</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`

Answer (score 33):

For me, this error was resulting from using some **`androidx`** libraries but then still having the old coordinate layout in some `layout.xml` files.

`build.gradle`:

`com.android.support:coordinatorlayout` -> `androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0-alpha1`

If you're using `androidx` then maybe this is your problem too. 
I had to update the other `v7` libraries like `Toolbar` as well.

See the `androidx` migration guide here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor

Comment: When using the Migration tool for Android Studio, one has to be careful that only the current flavor will be migrated! I have this problem when I tried to run another flavor, and I did not realize that the layout had not been migrated.

Answer (score 17):

For android studio try to add these dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution for eclipse

Problem what i faced is `R.Java` file is not generated under **support.design** in gen/ folder.

After doing the below steps `R.Java` file is generated. Main issue is **design** library is target to 22. Changing to 23 worked.

1. Import **support design library** from `\sdk\extras\android\support\design` to eclipse workspace.
2. Open `project.properties` of **AppCompat** and **design** Library and target it to **23**
3. Clean **Appcompat**, **design** and **YourProject**.
4. Run the app

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your activity set theme AppCompat

```
<activity
            android:name=".newApp.screens.main.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_launch"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemes"></activity>

  <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppThemes" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#673AB7</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#512DA8</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#00BCD4</item>
</style>
```