# Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout" using Buck

Tags: android, buck

I'm trying to get Buck working with the balnk application template from Android Studio.

#### `apps/snappy/BUCK`

```
android_binary(
  name = 'main',
  manifest = 'AndroidManifest.xml',
  keystore = '//keystores:debug',
  package_type = 'debug',
  deps = [
    '//java:main',
    '//res:res',
    '//keystores:debug',
  ],
)
```

#### `res/snappy/layout/activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.whitedrop.snappy.MainActivity">

    ....

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

#### `res/BUCK`

```
android_resource(
  name = 'res',
  res = 'snappy',
  package = 'com.whitedrop.snappy',
  deps = [
  '//libs:appcompat-v7',
  '//libs:design'
  ],
  visibility = [
    'PUBLIC',
  ]
)
```

#### `libs/BUCK`

```
android_prebuilt_aar(
  name = 'appcompat-v7',
  aar = 'appcompat-v7-23.0.1.aar',
  visibility = ['PUBLIC']
)
android_prebuilt_aar(
  name = 'design',
  aar = 'design-23.0.1.aar',
  visibility = ['PUBLIC']
)
```

#### output

```
                    Process com.whitedrop.snappy created for activity com.whitedrop.snappy/.MainActivity
                    PID: 2449   UID:    GIDs: 

ActivityManager  I  Start proc 2449:com.whitedrop.snappy/u0a61 for activity com.whitedrop.snappy/.MainActivity
            art  I  Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
 AndroidRuntime  D  Shutting down VM
                 E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                 E  Process: com.whitedrop.snappy, PID: 2449
                 E  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.whitedrop.snappy/com.whitedrop.snappy.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateExcept
                    ion: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                 ...E      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                 E      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                 E  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                 E      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
                 ....
                 E      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                 E      ... 10 more
                 E  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data
                    /app/com.whitedrop.snappy-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                 E      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                 ...
                 E      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
                 E      ... 19 more
                 E      Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                 E          at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
                 E ....     at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
                 E          at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
                 E          ... 23 more
                 E      Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                 E          at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                 E          at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                 E          at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                 E          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                 E          ... 22 more
                 E      Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
ActivityManager  W    Force finishing activity 1 com.whitedrop.snappy/.MainActivity
```

EDIT: my apk contains the CoordinatorLayout class in its dex file btw

EDIT2: full code can be found here https://github.com/vinz243/snappy

EDIT3: tried extending from AppCompatActivity:

```
vinz243@vm:~/snappy$ buck build app
[-] PROCESSING BUCK FILES...FINISHED 0.1s [100%]
[+] DOWNLOADING... (0.00 B/S, TOTAL: 0.00 B, 0 Artifacts)
[+] BUILDING...0.3s [67%] (16/20 JOBS, 0 UPDATED, 0.0% CACHE MISS)
 |=> IDLE
 |=> IDLE
 |=> //java:main...  0.2s (running javac[0.2s])
 |=> IDLE
/home/vinz243/snappy/java/com/whitedrop/snappy/MainActivity.java:12: error: cannot access android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       ^
  class file for android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder not found
/home/vinz243/snappy/java/com/whitedrop/snappy/MainActivity.java:14: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
        ^
/home/vinz243/snappy/java/com/whitedrop/snappy/MainActivity.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                ^
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class com.whitedrop.snappy.MainActivity
/home/vinz243/snappy/java/com/whitedrop/snappy/MainActivity.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                ^
  symbol:   method setContentView(int)
  location: class com.whitedrop.snappy.MainActivity
/home/vinz243/snappy/java/com/whitedrop/snappy/MainActivity.java:20: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
        ^
/home/vinz243/snappy/java/com/whitedrop/snappy/MainActivity.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
                ^
  symbol:   method getMenuInflater()
  location: class com.whitedrop.snappy.MainActivity
Errors: 6. Warnings: 0.
```

Here is the MainActivity.java:

```
package com.whitedrop.snappy;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

EDIT 5:

Fixed above error by adding support v4 to deps. Now I get when running:

```
 E  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.whitedrop.snappy/com.whitedrop.snappy.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
 E      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
 E  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
 E      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
 E  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 E      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
 E      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
 E      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
 E      ... 24 more
 E  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawableCompat;
 E      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$VdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:891)
 E  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
     "/data/app/com.whitedrop.snappy-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
 E      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
```

Comment: really no one o.O ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the versions you've mentioned in your `BUCK` config are correct.

In the code you've shared in your question i see `v23.0.1` for support and design libraries. In your github repository I see `v23.4.0`.

[image]

I'm suspecting this is the reason. Change to the correct version you've included in your libs folder and see if it works.

**Update in response to edit 5 in your question:**

The following two dependencies will help resolve the `VectorDrawableCompat ClassNotFoundException`. Include them in a suitable way for BUCK.

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0'
```

Comment: thanks got it working now!! the only problem is Idk which answer solved it, since @jitinsharma answer also helped, but yours as well -_-

Comment: revert each one by one and check. I'm also curious to know.

Comment: I think both adding libraries you said and extending AppCompatActivity helped

Comment: Btw I have a last question , why does it looks so ugly ? http://i.imgur.com/VnOcLk6.png I just copied code from visual sudio example which worked fine

Comment: I think except for the extra large menu options button on top-right, it looks as it should. Did you attempt to use a custom drawable or resize the options button?

Comment: No the code is exactly the same as the template, which looks good. And the menu button is what bother me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114531/discussion-between-androidmechanic-and-vinz243).

Answer (score 1):

Try extending `MainActivity` to `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`

And then a clean install.

Comment: THanks for you answer. i know get another message, see original post

Answer (score 0):

Not related to BUCK but for me, I came across this error when using a mix of `androidx` and `android.support.v7` libraries. See my solution for that version of this error here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52490825/1762493