# cannot find symbol class in support design library

Tags: android, module, android-support-library

I want to use the design support library in one of my modules.
The module is an Android library set as `com.android.library`.
I included the following lines to the `buil.gradle` file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

but i get an error when i try to use the resources from the design library.
**"cannot find symbol class R"** referred to `android.support.design.R`

Comment: Run SDK Manager as administrator and then install Android Support Library from Extras

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964009/classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-android-support-design-rstyleable

Answer (score 0):

> File -> invalidate caches
>
> then
>
> Restart application

OR

> Try Build > Rebuild Project

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio

Comment: unfortunately not!